# Impute missing covariates at random in Stata

Tags: stata

I am trying to randomly impute missing data for several covariates using Stata. I have never done this, and I am trying to use this code from a former employee:

```
local covarall calc_age educcat ipovcat_bl US_born alc_yn2 drug_yn lnlpcbsum tot_iod
local num = 0 
foreach j of local covarall {
    gen iflag_`j'=0
    replace iflag_`j'=1 if `j'==.
    local num = `num'+1000
    forvalues i = 1/476 { 
        sort `j' 
        count if `j'==. 
        di r(N)
        local num2 = `num'+`i'
        set seed `num2'
        replace `j' in `i'=`j'[1+int((400-r(N))*runiform())] if iflag_`j'[`i']==1  
    }
 }
```

When I run this, Stata just gives me this over and over forever:

```
(0 real changes made)
  0
0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to to start with something smaller that works. Now extend it a little bit and check the results. Repeat these steps until you've got a fully working implementation. Most of times software development isn't an exact science but trial and error, especially if you're new to a language/library/framework.

Comment: If you are going to analyze these imputed data, I suggest that you use Stata's Multiple Imputation (MI) commands. You'll need them if you want to get standard errors that properly reflect the between and within-imputation variability.

Answer (score 1):

The three messages seem interpretable as follows:

```
replace iflag_`j' = 1 if `j' == .
```

will lead to a message `(0 real changes made)` whenever that is so, meaning that the variable in question is never equal to system missing, the requirement for replacement.

```
count if `j' == .
```

will lead to the display of `0` in the same circumstance.

```
di r(N)
```

ditto. `count` shows a result by default and then the code insists that it be shown again. Strange style, but not a bug.

All that said the line

```
replace `j' in `i'=`j'[1+int((400-r(N))*runiform())] if iflag_`j'[`i'] == 1
```

is quite illegal. My best guess is that you have copied it incorrectly somehow and that it should have been

```
replace `j' =`j'[1+int((400-r(N))*runiform())] in `i' if iflag_`j'[`i'] == 1
```

but this too should produce the same message as the first if a value is not missing.

I add that it is utterly pointless to enter the innermost loop if there are no missing values in a variable: there is then nothing to impute.

Changing the seed every time a change is made is strange, but that is partly a matter of taste.